# Link Summon Vorticular Drumgon with another Link monster as material?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Can I use a Link-2 Dark Dragon monster and another Dark Dragon monster to summon [Vorticular Drumgon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Vorticular_Drumgon) or do I need the 3 Dark Dragon monsters?

Comment: updated my answer for you to consider :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Drumgon explicitly states you need to use 3 dark dragon type monsters.

If what you want to do were allowed, the text would read as follows:
2+ Dark Dragon monsters

Comment: @DarkCygnus sorry, my comment got posted too early. i added additional explanation and example.

Comment: Checked and you are correct my friend :) updating my answer and reversing my vote on yours (still, could use some more details and the reason why you cant)

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't**.

At first one may think you could. Extracting from [the rulebook](https://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/SD_RuleBook_EN_10.pdf), pages 14-15, emphasis mine:

> Normally, 1 monster equals 1 Link Material. But **when you use a
> Link Monster as material for another Link Summon**, you can **count
> it as either 1 monster, or as a number of monsters equal to its
> Link Rating**.

So, one can indeed use a Link-X monster and count it as X monsters.

**However**... [Vorticular Drumgon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Vorticular_Drumgon) has a **specific requirement** for their materials to be ***"3 Dark Dragon Monsters"***. Therefore, you are limited to use *exactly* 3 monsters. The ruling also covers that part and indicates so in the same pages (emphasis mine):

> Remember that when you Link Summon, you need to meet 3 goals:
>
> - The amount of materials you use matches the Link Rating (Link Monsters count as 1 OR their own Link Rating).
> - **The number of materials you use meets the number specified in the materials line or “recipe”.**
> - The materials match any other requirements in the materials line (such as only Effect Monsters, or only a specific Type of monster).

So, technically you can use a Link-2 Dark Dragon for the summon, but you would need *other 2 monsters* that meet the same requirements (being Dark Dragons), as Drumgon explicitly asks for 3 monsters (no more, no less).